# Crash in QApplication/QThread on RHEL / apache (__get_tls_addr returns 0)

Tags: linux, apache, qt, rhel

Our app crashes only when running on RHEL6 under apache (even if started standalone as httpd -X). When running using custom small http server or under another machine with Ubuntu it works fine.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe8f96d9f in ?? () from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffe8f96d9f in ?? () from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x00007fffe8f93a39 in QThread::currentThread() () from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#2  0x00007fffe90a05bc in QCoreApplicationPrivate::QCoreApplicationPrivate(int&, char**, unsigned int) ()
   from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x00007fffe7cbec63 in QApplicationPrivate::QApplicationPrivate(int&, char**, QApplication::Type, int) ()
   from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#4  0x00007fffe7cc811c in QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) () from /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so.4
```

There're several similar issues on the internet but none of them list any answer:

- https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/8616
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=675373
- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12923?cversion=0&cnum_hist=5

According to Qt source, I think that `QThreadData::current()` return NULL. But why can this happen?

Now, what I found via disassembly is that `__get_tls_addr` returns 0 (for Qt static threaddata var I suppose). Now, when I run custom http server, not apache, `__get_tls_addr` does return valid pointer.

I found that if I change `-ftls-model=initial-exec` to `-ftls-model=global-dynamic` then it works in RHEL/apache. What I still don't understand is why, what is specific about apache.

Comment: Since this is a server application, why do you use `QApplication` and not `QCoreApplication`?

Comment: With QCoreApplication it crashes in same way.

Comment: Understood. That still doesn't change the fact that you should be using `QCoreApplication`. A `QApplication` started on a Linux host without a DISPLAY will complain and, IIRC, die on startup. A most unfortunate situation.

Comment: You should post the last two paragraphs as an answer to your question :)

Comment: Maybe, but that's not an answer, just a workaround, unless I know why and what I am doing.

Comment: But it's a good start and worth +100 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `initial-exec` and `local-exec` model only makes sense for an application that starts by being `exec`'d. Things are supposed to fail if the module is not the main module, but a library. And fail they do.

What you've found out is that to use TLS from a library takes a different set of flags than when building a stand-alone executable. One wishes the qmake mkspecs took care of that on relevant compilers...

See [the tls-model attribute reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/language_ref/attr_tls_model.html).

Comment: That's interesting. I'll try to find out more about this, but I'll be glad if you provide a link with more details. Should I start with "ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage"?

Comment: Accepting even though I am going to research more.